# Глобальная кроссплатформенная симуляция нажатия клавиш клавиатуры C++/Qt

Tags: c++, qt, клавиатура

Необходимо симулировать нажатие на клавишу клавиатуры в определенный момент. Все бы ничего, но нужно то сделать глобально (то есть, не в окне программы, а в окне, которое сейчас находится в фокусе (блокнот, браузер, консоль и т.п.)) и кроссплатформенно (соответственно, winAPI с keybd_event не подойдет). Я попробовал вот это:

```
QKeyEvent* pe = new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_K, Qt::NoModifier);
QApplication::sendEvent(this, pe);
```

Но это работает только в текущем окне.

Comment: Qt это фреймворк для разработки приложений, а не швейцарский нож на все случаи жизни. Очень много вещей нужно писать своими руками, особенно таких, что выходят за рамки одного приложения.

Comment: @ixSci в общем, в этом и есть вопрос - как написать, куда посмотреть, что почитать. Я даже не знаю, с чего начать.

Comment: @ixSci вопрос именно в направлении мысли, не "дайте мне готовое решение"

Comment: Твое окно по идее это класс отнаследованый от QWidget, почему не реализовать этот ивент у каждого класса(окн) ? а лучше написать свой и отнаследоваться всеми окнами от него.

Comment: @АнтонИгнатьев нет-нет, здесь под "окном в фокусе" подразумевает вообще любое окно - в том числе и окно не этого приложения, консоль, браузер, блокнот и т.п.

Comment: вот сюда посмотрите https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795188/how-to-generate-key-press-events-in-qt-app-to-system-win7-simulate-user-press?rq=1 Но я с налету не уверен, есть ли возможность сделать просто кроссплатформенно

Comment: Если хотите кроссплатформенно, то пишите отдельно под каждую конкретную платформу реализуя некоторый интерфейс, общий для всех платформ.

Comment: Ну как же не знаете? Вот у Вас в вопросе: WinAPI и keybd_event, именно это и используйте.